# Scala compiler error

Tags: scala, sbt

Here is the classes -

```
    implicit def stringToSeq(single: String): Seq[String] = Seq(single)
  implicit def liftToOption[T](t: T): Option[T] = Some(t)

    sealed abstract class MailType
  case object Plain extends MailType
  case object Rich extends MailType
  case object MultiPart extends MailType

  case class Mail(from: (String, String), // (email, name)
                  to: Seq[String],
                  cc: Seq[String] = Seq.empty,
                  bcc: Seq[String] = Seq.empty,
                  subject: String,
                  message: String,
                  richMessage: Option[String] = None,
                  attachment: Option[(java.io.File)] = None
                  )
```

And here is how I'm using them -

```
new Mail (
                      from = ("xxx.@abc.com", "Shwetanka"),
                      to = opts(0),
                      subject = "Test Email",
                      message = "",
                      richMessage = htmlMsg(opts(1)).toString()
                    )
```

I'm getting compilation error -

```
    /home/shwetanka/projects/scala/tools/src/main/scala/Mailer.scala:32: not enough arguments for constructor Mail: (from: (String, String), to: Seq[String], cc: Seq[String], bcc: Seq[String], subject: String, message: String, richMessage: Option[String], attachment: Option[java.io.File])email.package.Mail
[error]                         send a new Mail (
[error]                                ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

I'm not able to figure out why it's not compiling. I'm using sbt and running this via 'run' command.

Comment: It is better to write `Option(t)`, but not `Some(t)`, cause if `t` is `null` it will return an awful `Some(null)`, but in case of Option it would be `None`

Comment: What are the opts() and htmlMsg() methods you use in the constructor example? It's hard to help you if you don't post a complete example.

Comment: key=val string split with '=' giving array. Not shown here but defined in the code.

Comment: When I run the code with idea12 compiler it gets compiled. When I use sbt to compile it gives above error. I removed cc and bcc from the constructor even then the same problem.

Comment: I've replaced `opts` and `htmlMsg` with Seq and Option, tried with :paste in sbt 0.12.4 and it runs fine

Comment: Yep.. exiting sbt, clearing target and then compiling again worked fine. No changes were required in the code.